# I can't get raw json from request body aiohttp. It is restructured from "1":[{"key1": "val1"},{}, ...] into "1[key1]":"val1",

Tags: json, python-3.x, http-post, aiohttp, hmac

I need to verify signature by taking json data and getting its hmac. To match signature which is sent from paying system i need data in identical form as it is sent from paying system, without any transformation. I can't just load binary data, because i have to sort keys and get rid of spaces. But I keep getting "enhancements" like `from "1":[{"key1": "val1"},{}, ...] into "1[key1]":"val1", ...`.

Everything went smooth with Flask `request.form.to_dict()`. But i have to use aiohttp and it lets me down. I tried `request.json()`, `request.read() # + getting json from it`. I  haven't found a solution yet.